# How to improve performance for dynamic api calls with large amount of data using Laravel PHP

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5, redis, performance-testing

I'm using zumata dynamic api calls to get hotel result based on my search  .

For Example : When we search any city , the  Zumata gives approx. 1000 hotels, for the 1000 hotels again I'm looping  filters like star rating and reviews rating. For each filters need to call different api's like 1000 api calls in background to get the final result.

I have already applied cache to store the result , but still its getting loading time high like about 5 mins. Is there any other way to reduce loading time ?

Or any better idea to increase performance speed other than cache storage.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can chunk your data and use it for processing.

```
Model::chunk(100, function ($chunked_results) {
 //do your work here
});
```

This will retrieve 100 rows each time and pass them to the callback function.

Refer this for more info [Chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#chunking-results)

Comment: I need to sorting as welll..if i chuncked the data ...again need to loop whole data ...

Comment: Try  DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->chunk(100, function($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        //
    }
});